# How to create a new branch from a tag?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I'd like to create a new master branch from an existing tag. Say I have a tag `v1.0`. How to create a new branch from this tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkout GIT tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582208/checkout-git-tag)

Answer (score 1298, accepted):

Wow, that was easier than I thought:

```
git checkout -b newbranch v1.0
```

---

If running the above command you get an error

> warning: refname 'v1.0' is ambiguous. 
> fatal: ambiguous object name: 'v1.0'

this is because you also have a branch with name `v1.0`. In this case specify `tags/` prefix:

```
git checkout -b newbranch tags/v1.0
```

Comment: Correct.  Note you also could have just set the master branch back to the point of the tag with `git reset --hard v1.0`

Comment: If this doesn't work because of "<tag> is not a valid commit" or a similar error (often when working on a shared repository), refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags#35979751

Comment: The suggestion from @wadesworld could work, but if anyone reads this and isn't 100% sure what it means to reset the master branch, *don't do that*.

Comment: This is a better answer that I found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35979751/3145960

Comment: `git switch -C` should be the more "modern" way; see the [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73153620/3429115)

Comment: If you get an error  "<tag> is not a valid commit" or a similar error", please make sure you have executed "git fetch --tags" first.

Answer (score 146):

If you simply want to create a new branch without immediately changing to it, you could do the following:

```
git branch newbranch v1.0
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it does exactly what is required. The accepted answer does something else not stated in the question.

Answer (score 146):

I used the following steps to create a new hot fix branch from a Tag.

**Syntax**

```sh
git checkout -b <New Branch Name> <TAG Name>
```

Steps to do it.

1. `git checkout -b NewBranchName v1.0`
2. Make changes to pom / release versions
3. Stage changes
4. `git commit -m "Update pom versions for Hotfix branch"`
5. Finally push your newly created branch to remote repository.

```sh
git push -u origin NewBranchName
```

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 19):

I have resolve the problem as below
1. Get the tag from your branch
2. Write below command

```
Example: git branch <Hotfix branch> <TAG>
    git branch hotfix_4.4.3 v4.4.3
    git checkout hotfix_4.4.3
```

or you can do with other command

```
git checkout -b <Hotfix branch> <TAG>
-b stands for creating new branch to local
```

once you ready with your hotfix branch, It's time to move that branch to github, you can do so by writing below command

```
git push --set-upstream origin hotfix_4.4.3
```

Comment: If you last release was `v4.4.3`, shouldn't your new branch be called hotfix_4.4.4

Answer (score 10):

An exemple of the only solution that works for me in the simple usecase where I am on a fork and I want to checkout a new branch from a tag that is on the main project repository ( here upstream )

```
git fetch upstream --tags
```

Give me

```
From https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak
   90b29b0e31..0ba9055d28  stage      -> upstream/stage
 * [new tag]    11.0.0     -> 11.0.0
```

Then I can create a new branch from this tag and checkout on it

`git checkout -b tags/<name> <newbranch>`

```
git checkout tags/11.0.0 -b v11.0.0
```

Comment: I think you have this backwards in your first example: `git checkout -b <newbranch> tags/<name>`

Answer (score 10):

At the time of writing this answer, the most up-to-date idiomatic git use is this command:

```
git switch -C branch tag
```

Answer (score 9):

The situation becomes a little bit problematic if we want to create a branch from a tag *with the same name*.

In this, and in similar scenarios, the important thing is to know: branches and tags are actually single-line text files in `.git/refs` directory, and we can reference them explicitly using their pathes below `.git`. Branches are called here "heads", to make our life more simple.

Thus, `refs/heads/master` is the real, explicit name of the `master` branch. And `refs/tags/cica` is the exact name of the tag named `cica`.

The correct command to create a branch named `cica` from the tag named `cica` is:

```
git branch cica refs/tags/cica
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Open branches/tags dropdown
2. Switch to 'Tags' tab
3. Select the required tag

[image]

Redirected to the tag repository—
[image]

4. Open branches/tags dropdown
5. Switch to 'Branches' tab
6. Start typing to create new branch with name

[image]

Comment: This question is about Git, not GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

My branch list (only **master** now)

[image: branch list]

My tag list (have three tags)

[image: tag list]

Switch to new branch **feature/codec** from **opus_codec** tag

```
git checkout -b feature/codec opus_codec
```

[image: switch to branch]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots if also text copy-paste would be enough.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer doesn’t add anything to the accepted answer from 2012.

Answer (score 2):

i was doing this like the other answers state with `git checkout <tag> -b <new-branch-name>` (and not the order of the tag vs branch being entered doesnt matter), even after doing a `git fetch` and was still getting a

```
fatal: 'my-tag' is not a commit and a branch 'temp-release-xxx' cannot be created from it
```

when i ran the more explicit `git fetch --tags`, then i was able to run the above command successfully

i thought `git fetch` would fetch all tags too, but sometimes you gotta nudge git i guess