# What is git tag, How to create tags & How to checkout git remote tag(s)

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-tag, git-refspec

when I checkout remote git tag use command like this:

```
git checkout -b local_branch_name origin/remote_tag_name
```

I got error like this:

> error: pathspec `origin/remote_tag_name` did not match any file(s) known to git.

I can find remote_tag_name when I use git tag command.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag

Answer (score 1734, accepted):

#### Let's start by explaining what a tag in git is

[image]

> A tag is used to label and mark a specific **commit** in the history.
> It is usually used to mark release points (eg. v1.0, etc.).

> Although a tag may appear similar to a branch, **a tag, however, does not change**. It points **directly** to a **specific commit** in the history and will not change unless explicitly updated.

[image]

---

You will not be able to checkout the tags if it's not locally in your repository so first, you have to `fetch` the tags to your local repository.

**First, make sure that the tag exists locally by doing**

```
# --all will fetch all the remotes.
# --tags will fetch all tags as well
$ git fetch --all --tags --prune
```

**Then check out the tag by running**

```
$ git checkout tags/<tag_name> -b <branch_name>
```

Instead of `origin` use the `tags/` prefix.

---

In this sample you have 2 tags version 1.0 & version 1.1 you can check them out with any of the following:

```
$ git checkout A  ...
$ git checkout version 1.0  ...
$ git checkout tags/version 1.0  ...
```

All of the above will do the same since the tag is only a pointer to a given commit.

[image]
origin: https://backlog.com/git-tutorial/img/post/stepup/capture_stepup4_1_1.png

---

## How to see the list of all tags?

```
# list all tags
$ git tag

# list all tags with given pattern ex: v-
$ git tag --list 'v-*'
```

---

## How to create tags?

There are 2 ways to create a tag:

```
# lightweight tag 
$ git tag v1.0

# annotated tag
$ git tag -a v1.0
```

The difference between the 2 is that when creating an annotated tag you can add metadata as you have in a git commit:
name, e-mail, date, comment & signature

[image]

## How to delete tags?

#### Delete a local tag

```
$ git tag -d <tag_name>
Deleted tag <tag_name> (was 000000)
```

**Note:** If you try to delete a non existig Git tag, there will be see the following error:

```
$ git tag -d <tag_name>
error: tag '<tag_name>' not found.
```

#### Delete remote tags

```
# Delete a tag from the server with push tags
$ git push --delete origin <tag name>
```

## How to clone a specific tag?

In order to grab the content of a given tag, you can use the `checkout` command. As explained above tags are like any other commits so we can use `checkout` and instead of using the SHA-1 simply replacing it with the *tag_name*

**Option 1:**

```
# Update the local git repo with the latest tags from all remotes
$ git fetch --all

# checkout the specific tag
$ git checkout tags/<tag> -b <branch>
```

**Option 2:**

#### Using the clone command

Since git supports *shallow clone* by adding the `--branch` to the clone command we can use the tag name instead of the branch name. Git knows how to "translate" the given SHA-1 to the relevant commit

```
# Clone a specific tag name using git clone 
$ git clone <url> --branch=<tag_name>
```

> **git clone --branch=**
>
> *`--branch` can also take tags and detaches the HEAD at that commit in the resulting repository.*

---

## How to push tags?

#### **`git push --tags`**

To push all tags:

```
# Push all tags
$ git push --tags
```

#### Using the `refs/tags` instead of just specifying the `<tagname>`.

Why?

- It's recommended to use `refs/tags` since sometimes tags can have the same name as your branches and a simple git push will push the branch instead of the tag

To push annotated tags and current history chain tags use:

#### **`git push --follow-tags`**

This flag `--follow-tags` pushes both **commits** and **only tags** that are both:

- Annotated tags (so you can skip local/temp build tags)
- Reachable tags (an ancestor) from the current branch (located on the history)

[image]

From Git 2.4 you can set it using configuration

```
$ git config --global push.followTags true
```

---

Cheatsheet:
[image]

---

Comment: nice. `git checkout A`.  what is `A`? How did you create `A`?

Comment: @Honey `A` is a commit hash

Comment: @GiovanniLovato The flow chart is a third party one. The link to the image is https://backlog.com/git-tutorial/img/post/stepup/capture_stepup4_1_1.png which is from this page https://backlog.com/git-tutorial/stepup/stepup4_1.html of the website called Git Beginner's Guide for Dummies (backlog.com).

Comment: It's worth noting that `git checkout tags/<tag_name> -b <branch_name>` does require the `-b <branch_name>`. `git checkout tags/<tag_name>` gave me a detached head. As per this [article about detached head](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit), you avoid a detached head by temporarily creating and deleting a branch. This is quite an alien work flow. Clearly I as a git user need to get used to creating and deleting branches for fun and profit.

Comment: Excellent answer, but it doesn't address whether you can add multiple tags to a single commit.

Comment: Should "hexadecimal version names" instead be "Git commit ID (a 40-digit SHA-1 hash)"?

Comment: Came here looking for 'How to checkout git tag'.  While I like most of the pretty pictures, this answer (in line with the question title before being edited to suit the post) would be better imo by removing the top cartoon and replacing it with a text version of the cheat sheet as a tl/dr;.

Answer (score 214):

(This answer took a while to write, and [codeWizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35979751/1256452) is correct in aim and essence, but not entirely complete, so I'll post this anyway.)

---

There is no such thing as a "remote Git tag".  There are only "tags".  I point all this out not to be pedantic,<sup>1</sup> but because there is a great deal of confusion about this with casual Git users, and the Git documentation is not very helpful<sup>2</sup> to beginners.  (It's not clear if the confusion comes because of poor documentation, or the poor documentation comes because this is inherently somewhat confusing, or what.)

There *are* "remote branches", more properly called "remote-tracking branches", but it's worth noting that these are actually local entities.  There are no remote tags, though (unless you (re)invent them).  There are only local tags, so you need to get the tag locally in order to use it.

The general form for names for specific commits—which Git calls *references*—is any string starting with `refs/`.  A string that starts with `refs/heads/` names a branch; a string starting with `refs/remotes/` names a remote-tracking branch; and a string starting with `refs/tags/` names a tag.  The name `refs/stash` is the stash reference (as used by `git stash`; note the lack of a trailing slash).

There are some unusual special-case names that do not begin with `refs/`: `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` in particular are all also names that may refer to specific commits (though `HEAD` normally contains the name of a branch, i.e., contains `ref: refs/heads/branch`).  But in general, references start with `refs/`.

One thing Git does to make this confusing is that it allows you to omit the `refs/`, and often the word after `refs/`.  For instance, you can omit `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/` when referring to a local branch or tag—and in fact you *must* omit `refs/heads/` when checking out a local branch!  You can do this whenever the result is unambiguous, or—as we just noted—when you must do it (for `git checkout branch`).

It's true that references exist not only in your own repository, but also in remote repositories.  However, Git gives you access to a remote repository's references only at very specific times: namely, during `fetch` and `push` operations.  You can also use `git ls-remote` or `git remote show` to see them, but `fetch` and `push` are the more interesting points of contact.

#### Refspecs

During `fetch` and `push`, Git uses strings it calls *refspecs* to transfer references between the local and remote repository.  Thus, it is at these times, and via refspecs, that two Git repositories can get into sync with each other.  Once your names are in sync, you can use the same name that someone with the remote uses.  There is some special magic here on `fetch`, though, and it affects both branch names and tag names.

You should think of `git fetch` as directing your Git to call up (or perhaps text-message) another Git—the "remote"—and have a conversation with it.  Early in this conversation, the remote lists all of its references: everything in `refs/heads/` and everything in `refs/tags/`, along with any other references it has.  Your Git scans through these and (based on the usual fetch refspec) *renames* their branches.

Let's take a look at the normal refspec for the remote named `origin`:

```
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
$
```

This refspec instructs your Git to take every name matching `refs/heads/*`—i.e., every branch on the remote—and change its name to `refs/remotes/origin/*`, i.e., keep the matched part the same, changing the branch name (`refs/heads/`) to a remote-tracking branch name (`refs/remotes/`, specifically, `refs/remotes/origin/`).

It is *through this refspec* that `origin`'s branches become your remote-tracking branches for remote `origin`.  Branch name becomes remote-tracking branch name, with the name of the remote, in this case `origin`, included.  The plus sign `+` at the front of the refspec sets the "force" flag, i.e., your remote-tracking branch will be updated to match the remote's branch name, regardless of what it takes to make it match.  (Without the `+`, branch updates are limited to "fast forward" changes, and tag updates are simply ignored since Git version 1.8.2 or so—before then the same fast-forward rules applied.)

#### Tags

But what about tags?  There's no refspec for them—at least, not by default.  You can set one, in which case the form of the refspec is up to you; or you can run `git fetch --tags`.  Using `--tags` has the effect of adding `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` to the refspec, i.e., it brings over all tags (<s>but does not update *your* tag if you already have a tag with that name, *regardless of what the remote's tag says*</s> Edit, Jan 2017: as of Git 2.10, testing shows that `--tags` forcibly updates your tags from the remote's tags, as if the refspec read `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`; this may be a difference in behavior from an earlier version of Git).

Note that there is no renaming here: if remote `origin` has tag `xyzzy`, and you don't, and you `git fetch origin "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"`, you get `refs/tags/xyzzy` added to your repository (pointing to the same commit as on the remote).  If you use `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` then your tag `xyzzy`, if you have one, is *replaced* by the one from `origin`.  That is, the `+` force flag on a refspec means "replace my reference's value with the one my Git gets from their Git".

#### Automagic tags during fetch

For historical reasons,<sup>3</sup> if you use neither the `--tags` option nor the `--no-tags` option, `git fetch` takes special action.  Remember that we said above that the remote starts by displaying to your local Git *all* of its references, whether your local Git wants to see them or not.<sup>4</sup>  Your Git takes note of all the tags it sees at this point.  <s>Then, as it begins downloading any commit objects it needs to handle whatever it's fetching, if one of those commits has the same ID as any of those tags, git will add that tag—or those tags, if multiple tags have that ID—to your repository.</s>

Edit, Jan 2017: testing shows that the behavior in Git 2.10 is now: If their Git provides a tag named *T*, *and* you do not have a tag named *T*, *and* the commit ID associated with *T* is an ancestor of one of their branches that your `git fetch` is examining, your Git adds *T* to your tags with or without `--tags`.  Adding `--tags` causes your Git to obtain *all* their tags, and also force update.

#### Bottom line

You may have to use `git fetch --tags` to get their tags.  If their tag names conflict with your existing tag names, you *may* (depending on Git version) even have to delete (or rename) some of your tags, and then run `git fetch --tags`, to get their tags.  Since tags—unlike remote branches—do not have automatic renaming, your tag names must match their tag names, which is why you can have issues with conflicts.

In *most* normal cases, though, a simple `git fetch` will do the job, bringing over their commits and their matching tags, and since they—whoever they are—will tag commits at the time they publish those commits, you will keep up with their tags.  If you don't make your own tags, nor mix their repository and other repositories (via multiple remotes), you won't have any tag name collisions either, so you won't have to fuss with deleting or renaming tags in order to obtain their tags.

#### When you need qualified names

I mentioned above that you can omit `refs/` almost always, and `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` and so on most of the time.  But when *can't* you?

The complete (or near-complete anyway) answer is in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Git will resolve a name to a commit ID using the six-step sequence given in the link.  Curiously, tags override branches: if there is a tag `xyzzy` and a branch `xyzzy`, and they point to different commits, then:

```
git rev-parse xyzzy
```

will give you the ID to which the tag points.  However—and this is what's missing from `gitrevisions`—`git checkout` prefers branch names, so `git checkout xyzzy` will put you on the branch, disregarding the tag.

In case of ambiguity, you can almost always spell out the ref name using its full name, `refs/heads/xyzzy` or `refs/tags/xyzzy`.  (Note that this *does* work with `git checkout`, but in a perhaps unexpected manner: `git checkout refs/heads/xyzzy` causes a detached-HEAD checkout rather than a branch checkout.  This is why you just have to note that `git checkout` will use the short name as a branch name first: that's how you check out the branch `xyzzy` even if the tag `xyzzy` exists.  If you want to check out the tag, you can use `refs/tags/xyzzy`.)

Because (as `gitrevisions` notes) Git will try `refs/name`, you can also simply write `tags/xyzzy` to identify the commit tagged `xyzzy`.  (If someone has managed to write a valid reference named `xyzzy` into `$GIT_DIR`, however, this will resolve as `$GIT_DIR/xyzzy`.  But normally only the various `*HEAD` names should be in `$GIT_DIR`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Okay, okay, "not *just* to be pedantic". :-)

<sup>2</sup>Some would say "very not-helpful", and I would tend to agree, actually.

<sup>3</sup>Basically, `git fetch`, and the whole concept of remotes and refspecs, was a bit of a late addition to Git, happening around the time of Git 1.5.  Before then there were just some ad-hoc special cases, and tag-fetching was one of them, so it got grandfathered in via special code.

<sup>4</sup>If it helps, think of the remote Git as a [flasher](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flasher), in the slang meaning.

Comment: Great writeup. One tiny nit: `git fetch` will only fetch the remote's tags given the `--tags` arg.

Comment: @cweekly: the behavior of `--tags`, `--no-tags`, and default is actually quite tricky. The default is to bring in tags that you don't have that are in the commits you're bringing in. (See the Jan 2017 edit.) But there are glitches here as well, and modern Git is having its --tags/--no-tags handling code revised yet again, which will probably lead to yet more special corner cases.

Answer (score 46):

**In order to checkout a git tag ,** you would execute the following command

```
git checkout tags/tag-name -b branch-name
```

eg as mentioned below.

```
 git checkout tags/v1.0 -b v1.0-branch
```

**To find the remote tags:**

```
git ls-remote --tags origin
```

**Create a tag with the given tag message**

```
git tag <tag_name> -a -m "tag message"
```

**To Push a single tag to remote**

```
git push origin <tag_name>
```

**Push all tags to remote**

```
git push origin --tags
```

Answer (score 5):

When I want the code at a tag, I may not want to create a branch (typically, I only need a full branch if I'll be hotfixing it).

To temporarily rewind your branch to the code at the tag, do this:

```
git reset --hard tags/1.2.3
```

I can use it briefly as needed, then get back to HEAD of the branch when I'm done, with a simple `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the specific tag code try to create a new branch add get the tag code in it.
I have done it by command : `$git checkout -b newBranchName tagName`

Answer (score 1):

This is bit out of context but in case you are here because you want to tag a specific commit like i do

Here's a command to do that :-

Example:

```
git tag -a v1.0 7cceb02 -m "Your message here"
```

Where `7cceb02` is the beginning part of the commit id.

You can then push the tag using `git push origin v1.0`.

You can do `git log` to show all the commit id's in your current branch.