# Creating a private fork from a public repository with base/trunk being an upstream tag

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, git-tag

## Repository Setup

### Fork a Private Repository

#### Clone public repo into private repo

```
git clone --bare git@github.com:`upstream`/`upstream-repo`.git
cd `upstream-repo`.git
git push --mirror git@github.com:`origin`/`origin-repo`.git
```

#### Create working directory

```
git clone git@github.com:`origin`/`origin-repo`.git
git remote add upstream git@github.com:`upstream`/`upstream-repo`
git fetch upstream
```

#### delete all branches except master and legacy (for clarity)

```
git push origin --delete `all branches excpt. master and legacy`
```

#### set up remote-tracking branches

```
git branch --set-upstream-to upstream/master master
git branch --set-upstream-to upstream/legacy legacy
```

### let the trunk branch be a tag from the upstream

> There is no such thing as a "remote Git tag"

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35981459/8548024

So the tag is a local tag that can be updated with `git fetch upstream --tags`

#### Create the origin trunk (named `origin-repo`) from the local tag

```
git checkout tags/X.XX.XX -b `origin-repo`
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/`origin-repo` `origin-repo`
git push origin `origin-repo`
git pull
```

### Apply a private diff

```
git checkout -b feat-diff
git apply feat-diff
git commit -m "applied feat-diff"
git push origin feat-diff
```

Then a pull request for feat-diff (in the GitHub UI)
with base: `origin-repo`

**I expected my network graph to look like this:**

```
master (upstream/master) ------------UM1--UM2--UM3--UM4--UM5------
                                       \
legacy (upstream/legacy)               UL1--UL2--UL3--UL4---------
                                              \
origin-repo (origin/origin-repo)              OR1--OR2-------OR3--
                                                     \      /
feat-diff (origin/feat-diff)                         FD1--FD2
```

Instead I got this graph. (My feature branch goes back all the way to the tag I used)

[image: The origin-repo looks like a feature branch and the feature branch looks like the origin]

So it looks like my main branch (origin-repo) is a feature branch of the actual feature branch and the feature branch goes all the way back to the tag.

Why is that so and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it looks like my main branch (origin-repo) is a feature branch of the actual feature branch

Given a commit structure like

```
  B <--(branch1)
 /
A
 \
  C <--(branch2)
```

there is no special relationship between `A` and either one of these branches over the other.  Maybe `branch1` happens to be called `master`.  Maybe `branch2` is called `feature`.  Maybe `master` existed at `A` before `feature` was created, but if so `git` doesn't remember or care about that detail.

Point being, "feature branch" is a descriptive label useful to people as they understand a branching model.  It is *not* a "physically real" concept in git.  Both branches are branches, and that is all.

> and the feature branch goes all the way back to the tag.

Branches don't "go back" at all.  A branch is a pointer to a commit.  You might think of that commit as the "tip of the branch" or something like that, but in fact that's all the branch is.  There is no path through history that's "also part of the branch".  There can be one or more paths through history that are *reachable from* the branch, but those same paths may be reachable from another branch, and there is no special relationship between the path(s) and any one branch over another.

**So what you're really getting at** is that your visualization tool, in trying to cater to the abstractions we like to impose over branches - such as a relationship between a path of commits and a branch - "guessed wrong" about which branch you'd like to see associated with which path through history.

I can't tell you why it "guessed wrong".  I can tell you it had to guess, because the relationship you wanted to see isn't a real thing.