# two git branches at same commit, "git log a..b" shows a difference

Tags: git, github

I have a `master` and a `prod` branch that track remotes of the same name and both are the same commit according to `git log`

[image: picture of git log telling me that they're on the same commit]

[image: here's a second picture of github showing me that they're pointing to the same thing]

yet, when I type `git log prod..master` I get a bunch of commits from the last ~week that seems to be in both branches.

if I `git branch -vv` I can see `prod` tracking `origin/prod`, and if i `git branch -a | grep prod` I get

```
* prod
remotes/origin/prod
```

also, when I `git checkout prod` I get `warning: refname 'prod' is ambiguous.`

I'm totally stumped about what's happening -- can someone give me a... pointer (sorry).

Comment: do you have a tag named prod as well?

Comment: The `warning: refname 'prod' is ambiguous` means CodeWizard's answer (and comment) are right.

Comment: Do you have a folder named 'prod'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it isn't a tag, it must be some other reference whose priority in the search order "wins" vs a branch name.  [The gitrevisions documentation](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) provides a six-step process for resolving a symbolic name to a hash ID:

> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

When you write `git log prod..master`, the names `prod` and `master` each go through this six-step process.  If there is a file in `$GIT_DIR` named `prod` that contains a hash ID, step 1 will find that file and use its valule.  If not, Git will go on to step 2, to see if `refs/prod` names a hash ID.  If not, Git will go on to step 3 (which tries to resolve `prod` as a tag name) and if that fails, go on to step 4 (which tries to resolve `prod` as a branch name).

Given that the `git log --oneline` image shows that `refs/heads/prod` *does* exist, step 4 will definitely succeed, producing the value `9e0ae5792f3c80e76a2b41ed325fa1a20d599a4f` (if I transcribed it correctly).  So the only way that `prod` could resolve to a *different* hash ID is if one of the earlier steps succeeds.

A tag name is the most likely culprit, but [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343950/two-git-branches-at-same-commit-git-log-a-b-shows-a-difference#comment93572389_53344069) implies that there are no tag names: they would show up in `git tag --list` output.  That leaves either step 1 or step 2 as the remaining possibilities.

Note that when you use `git checkout`, Git *doesn't* apply the six-step process in that order: first, Git tries to use the name as a branch name.  Only if that fails will Git fall back on the six-step process; if that succeeds, `git checkout` will detach your HEAD, checking out the commit by its hash ID.  So that's why you can `git checkout prod` and get on the branch, even though the reference name is ambiguous (has some meaning in addition to `refs/heads/prod`).

The command `git for-each-ref` will print out every reference (everything that steps 2 through 6 could match).  It will not check for `$GIT_DIR/prod` (which step 1 would match), but you can do that yourself by looking inside the `.git` directory to see if there is a file named `prod`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you got a bunch of differences while your git log mark that the local prod and the remote prod branch are the same it looks like you have a tag named `prod`

if you are not familiar with tags read this answer:
[What is git tag, How to create tags & How to checkout git remote tag(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags/35979751#35979751)

In short, use this command to check to see your tags:

```
git tag --list
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help! I'm so stumped here.

I tried `git fetch --all --tags` and then `git tag --list` but there's no output, which makes me feel like there are no tags. did i do that wrong, or should I explore down a different path?