# When Git is creating a tag (`git tag -a` command w/out specifiing commit) - does it get reference from HEAD?

Tags: git, git-tag

It is not explained in detail (IMHO) in docs https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging how `git tag -a` works.

- will tag point to last or next commit or ?
- does `tag -a` copy HEAD to make a pointer (if so, than to last commit)?

P.S. maybe it can be inferred from very technical answer (not one which is accepted, other one) in **[What is git tag, How to create tags & How to checkout git remote tag(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags/35981459#35981459)** but I have not grasped such details of git yet.

Answer (score 1):

Tags are static references in git. You can think of them as a pointer to a commit that never moves. The commit referred to by HEAD gets a new static reference when you do `git tag -a`, so in a sense you can say that the HEAD reference is copied. It's a bit more complicated because the type of object is different. You can of course create a tag for any other commit as well, in which case HEAD has nothing to do with the tag.