# How to compile Mono on Debian 9.3

Tags: mono, debian

I tried to compile mono on Debian 9.3 using commands

```
apt-get install git autoconf libtool automake build-essential gettext cmake python
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://github.com/mono/mono/archive/mono-5.18.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf mono-5.18.1.0.tar.gz
cd mono-mono-5.18.1.0
./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/m518
./configure --prefix=/opt/m518
make
```

but make throws strange error

```
...
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/local/src/mono-mono-5.18.1.0/mono/btls'
mkdir -p build-shared
(cd build-shared && CC="gcc" CXX="g++" /usr/bin/cmake -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt/m518 -D BTLS_ROOT:PATH=/usr/local/src/mono-mono-5.18.1.0/external/boringssl -D SRC_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/src/mono-mono-5.18.1.0/mono/btls -D BTLS_CFLAGS:STRING=""  -DBTLS_ARCH="x86_64" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 /usr/local/src/mono-mono-5.18.1.0/mono/btls)
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:27 (message):
  SET ARCH: x86_64


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /usr/local/src/mono-mono-5.18.1.0/external/boringssl

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/local/src/mono-mono-5.18.1.0/mono/btls/build-shared/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Makefile:607: recipe for target 'build-shared/Makefile' failed
make[3]: *** [build-shared/Makefile] Error 1
```

How to fix this so that mono can  compiled ?

/usr/local/src/mono-mono-5.18.1.0/external/boringssl directory is empty.

**Update**

I compiled Mono as described in answer. MVC Application does not start. Apache errorlog contains error that string.split is not found (full erroe below). How to fix this so that application can run.

```
[Fri Mar 29 23:26:57.643727 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 28163:tid 140067959029824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) mod_mono/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 29 23:26:57.643846 2019] [core:notice] [pid 28163:tid 140067959029824] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'string.Split' not found.
  at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadRootData (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Configuration.Configuration config, System.Boolean overrideAllowed) [0x00007] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/SectionGroupInfo.cs:273 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.ReadConfigFile (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.String fileName) [0x000ce] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:572 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Load () [0x00043] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:532 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Init (System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigSystem system, System.String configPath, System.Configuration.Configuration parent) [0x0005d] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:138 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00056] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:96 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00038] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:91 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x0000d] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/InternalConfigurationFactory.cs:41 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationInternal (System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, System.Reflection.Assembly calling_assembly, System.String exePath) [0x000ea] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:119 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x0000e] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:49 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x0001f] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:52 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:61 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:159 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:173 
  at Mono.WebServer.Options.Settings.Setting`1[T]..ctor (System.String name, Mono.WebServer.Options.Settings.Parser`1[T] parser, System.String description, System.String appSetting, System.String environment, System.Nullable`1[T] defaultValue, System.String prototype) [0x000c5] in /usr/local/src/xsp-4.6/src/Mono.WebServer/Options/Settings/Setting.cs:55 
  at Mono.WebServer.Options.Settings.NullableSetting`1[T]..ctor (System.String name, Mono.WebServer.Options.Settings.Parser`1[T] parser, System.String description, System.String appSetting, System.String environment, System.Nullable`1[T] defaultValue, System.String prototype) [0x00003] in /usr/local/src/xsp-4.6/src/Mono.WebServer/Options/Settings/NullableSetting.cs:33 
  at Mono.WebServer.Options.Settings.NullableUInt16Setting..ctor (System.String name, System.String description, System.String appSetting, System.String environment, System.Nullable`1[T] defaultValue, System.String prototype) [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/xsp-4.6/src/Mono.WebServer/Options/Settings/NullableUInt16Setting.cs:35 
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.ConfigurationManager..ctor (System.String name, System.Boolean quietDefault, System.String rootDefault) [0x0009c] in /usr/local/src/xsp-4.6/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ConfigurationManager.cs:43 
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, System.Boolean root, Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost ext_apphost, System.Boolean v_quiet) [0x0001a] in /usr/local/src/xsp-4.6/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:77 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server:RealMain (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00034] in /usr/local/src/xsp-4.6/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:58
```

Comment: The `external` directory are for git submodules (https://github.com/mono/mono#working-with-submodules) otherwise you would need to manually install each submodule's code set at the correct commit for the mono version that you are building.

Comment: external directory contains lot of empty subdirectories. It looks like tar file does not contain those contents. Probably I dont need them. Should I fill those so that Mono can compiled? If yes, should all those directories loaded manually from Github or is there easier way ?

Comment: Instead of using a tar ball, I always use `git` to pull the code set (`git clone --recursive https://github.com/mono/mono.git`) thus everything is available... Could you do it manually, sure, but, is it worth the time... not for me...

Comment: I need to install newer Mono for production system for ASP.NET MVC application. Current git version is not tested and may contain serious bugs. How to download latest release version with all files required to compile? I don't know git, is there some git command instead of using wget ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shallow clone the specific branch/tag that you need:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/mono/mono.git --branch=mono-5.18.1.0
cd mono
make install
```

re: [What is git tag, How to create tags & How to checkout git remote tag(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags)

re: https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-5.18.1.0

Comment: I tried but got error `Cloning into 'mono'...
fatal: Remote branch 5.18.1.0 not found in upstream origin
`

Comment: Typo, use `mono-5.18.1.0` (I have the correct link in the answer, but the wrong usage in the branch option).

Comment: I compiled mono, xsp and libgdiplus from github. . Trying to run apache causes exception that string.split is not found. I update question and provided full stack trace. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Andrus You really should ask this as a different question.... If you create a console app that uses "System" and contains a `string.Split` method, does it fail the same way? ... String.Split is a part of the ref. source, so unless that did not get compiled into System.dll (do not know how that would even happen): https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L925

Comment: I posted it as separate question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428938/how-to-run-mvc-application-with-newer-mono-in-debian-9-3. New Mono was installed in `/opt/m518`. How to use it for compiling console application? Should environment changed or can I invoke compiler in `/opt/m518` directly?

Comment: It it works with older, 5.4.1.6 version, if `git clone --recursive https://github.com/mono/mono.git --branch=mono-5.4.1.6` is used. It looks like something is broken in newer mono.