# Git - fetch tags only?

Tags: git, git-fetch

Is there a way to fetch only tags? When I run `git fetch --tags`, it fetches tags along with other branches that I don't care about, so I end up removing those remote branches after they were fetched.

Is there a possibility to use some filter to just look for tags, excluding everything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "git fetch --tags" include "git fetch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204190/does-git-fetch-tags-include-git-fetch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags/35979751#35979751