# How can I show all versions of my git repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm working in a project, in which I always make npm version patch and today I wish to :

- View all versions
- Checkout a specific version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using tags:

Read this answer: [What is git tag, How to create tags & How to checkout git remote tag(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags/35979751#35979751)

---

#### Checkout to a specific version

**Few options, too many to describe here**

1. Checkout commit

   ```
   # checkout any given commit
   git checkout <hash>
   ```
2. Revert to commit

   ```
   # Reset the working tree to the desired commit
   git reset <HASH/TAG> --hard
   ```

Comment: git reset 8.11.0 --hard => output:
fatal: ambiguous argument '8.11.0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'