# Checking out a git tag actually does another

Tags: git, git-tag

It seems odd to me this behavior, I have a git tag, lets say tag-a, when I checked it out by running the following:

```
git checkout tag-a
```

it checks out tag-b

```
user@server xxx ~/path/git-local-folder ((tag-b))
```

I would guess there is some sort of relationship between tag-a and tag-b but I don't know what it is and the logic of it

Comment: Do both tags point to the same commit? What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: good question, it says: "HEAD detached at tag-a" I am even more confused. I am trying to undestand the logic here, git reference page doesn't help me much with  that.

Comment: `HEAD detached at tag-a` means you have checked out `tag-a`. I don't know what shows the `tag-b` thing but I think this is not git (maybe your shell).

Comment: I'm using git bash

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Detached head generally means that you are not working from a branch.  You cannot checkout a tag directly, since it is a tag not a branch.  To create a branch use `-b` followed by the branch name to create when checking out the tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags

Comment: @dan1st the provided commands is already the minimal-"complete"-verifiable example. They are 2 tags which I don't know how they are related that when I checkout out, it shows on the git bash the other tag. if I could reproduce this scenario I would be able to understand such case and it would be unecessary to request help here. Also, this seems to be a scenario that hasn't been covered in previous stackoverflow questions therefore a helpful material for people in the future facing similar, perharps rare, situation

Comment: https://devconnected.com/how-to-checkout-git-tags/

Comment: yes but you didn't say how you got this result. (what tag was created earlier, how many commits are between those tags, does one tag's commit exist in the commit hierarchy of the other tag?)

Comment: Why would you check out a tag? This always detaches the head. It's a very odd thing to do. Can you explain your goal?

Comment: It seems likely that your prompt-setting code is getting confused by the detached HEAD status and printing something bogus. Where did you get the prompt-setting code?

Comment: @matt You would check out a tag for the same reason you created the tag in the first place: because it referred to some significant revision of the repository, such as a released version of the product. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["git checkout" command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) has several modes of operation, which it selects automatically based on the kind of argument you give it. The ones relevant right now are:

- If you give it a *branch name*, it updates the working tree and staging area to the current commit referenced by that branch, *and updates the HEAD marker to the name of that branch*. Subsequent operations, such as "git commit" then know to move that branch pointer.
- If you give it a reference to a commit *other than* a branch name, it updates the working tree and staging area in the same way, but *doesn't record any branch name as HEAD*. This is referred to as a "detached HEAD", and a subsequent "git commit" *won't move any branch pointer*. A tag name falls into this category.

Note that the newer ["git switch" command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) forces you to make this distinction explicitly: if the argument is not a branch name, it will fail unless you specify the `--detach` option.

Now, when your prompt tries to display the currently checked out branch, the simplest place to look is in the HEAD file. But if you are in a "detached HEAD" state, that will *just contain a commit hash*, regardless of how you chose that commit. So the display code has to pick something to show instead of the branch name. It can look if there are any tags pointing at the currently checked out commit, but if there is more than one tag pointing at it, it doesn't know which one you used, and just has to guess.

In your case, "tag-a" and "tag-b" presumably reference the same commit. So once you check out that commit, the prompt you're using looks for a tag, and finds "tag-b", even when what you actually typed was "tag-a", or even the commit hash.