# It was confused when I use "git name-rev --name-only HEAD"

Tags: git

ok，I have met a difficult problem:

1. I had a branch named A, and I checked out a new branch B based on A.
2. I committed something on B
3. Then I merged B into A, git used Fast-Forward mechanism to do that，now my branches as below:
   [image: branch now]

4. I checked back A, so now I was on branch A.
5. Now To get the current branch name, I executed command "git name-rev --name-only HEAD"  and I got branch B!!???But I was on branch A!!

so what does "git name-rev --name-only" do? Why does the above problem occur? Was I using the wrong command?

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me with that！

Comment: But you didn't ask git which branch you're currently on. You asked it to name a commit when in fact the commit has several names. You will get one of those names. If instead, you want to know the branch you're currently on, use `git branch --show-current`.

Comment: Instead of asking what `git name-rev ...` does, would it make more sense to ask you what you wanted to accomplish?

Comment: If you actually want to know how git determines which name to show you, then I don't know. I suspect it is not a guarantee which name it comes up with, just one of the names attached to it, but it might be influenced by such things as timestamp of branch files on disk or git commit id's or whatever. I don't know. It's a good question.

Comment: thank you !@ Lasse V. Karlsen. Actually i just wanna to know my current branch name, but if i am on a clear branch  and execute the   "git name-rev --name-only HEAD" ,i will get the correct branch name, so what does that command really do? Are there any blogs or webs to introduce it?

Comment: yeah, purpose-driven. I have another question: Can I use the "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" command to get the current branch name?Because I got something wrong when i used "git branch --show-current"

Comment: I'd avoid the `git name-rev` command. It doesn't seem very useful (use `git describe` for the typical use case for which people try to use `git name-rev`). To get the *current* branch name, use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` (perhaps with `--short`) or `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` or `git branch --show-current`.

Comment: These three are all subtly different, in terms of what they do in special situations: in particular, detached HEAD, and orphan/unborn branch cases.

Comment: I answered a similar question recently here, discussing the case of checking out a tag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606334/157957

Comment: @torek thank you!  when i used "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" in Fast-Forward mechanism ， i got the real current branch name.

Comment: @IMSoPIthank you！I would learn from that after a while!