# Is head always pointing to master on remote?

Tags: git

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582208/checkout-git-tag/5582368#5582368), we explain that HEAD is a pointer. But I'm confused, I checked my repo and I have 'remotes/origin/master' and 'remotes/origin/HEAD'. Can we just point remote head to somewhere to that a user cloning a repo is already on another branch?

Comment: Wait, this file exists? `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`? If so, that means you have a branch called "HEAD".

Comment: Maybe, not sure where it came from. I'm wondering if it was created by my cvs2git export... CVS has a HEAD, maybe that is why I have it in my remotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/912144). It points you to [this article](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2008/12/setting-default-git-branch-in-bare.html) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/912144). For a GitHub repository, you can also follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838756/912144).

In short, if you have access to the remote repository, you can do this on the remote repository itself:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/mybranch
```

Or on GitHub, do so [through the admin page](https://github.com/blog/421-pick-your-default-branch).